# Ho to find matching files name by file extension

Tags: python

Given a directory path , how can I search for a file names with extension type of lets say extension `.dat` only and return array of them?

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of `glob`.

```
import glob
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(dir_path, '*.dat')):
    print filename
```

For complete documentation please go to the [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) page.